# Подгрузка меню сайта с mssql

Tags: php, веб-программирование, sql-server

Добрый день, проблема в следующем, имеется БД MSSQL  с полями:
**id(tinyint), tittle(ntext), parent_id (tinyint)**
*id* поле-это автоинкремент
*tittle* - это описание поля
*parent_id* - идентификатор родительского эллмента меню (меню многоуровневое) значение поля *parent_id* указывает, на родительский эллемент меню (*id*), например если *parent_id* = 4 значит этот эллеменет должен идти за эллементом с *id*=4 (многоуровневый массив)

что я хочу,хочу я что-бы меню подгружалось с БД, собственно вот листинг:

**config.php**

```
     <?php



    ////////////////////////// НАСТРОЙКА СОЕДИНЕНИЯ С БД/////////////////////////
    $serverName = "isuo-db.chtpz.ru,1433";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"doc", "UID"=>"doc", "PWD"=>"isuodoc");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn ) {  
    }else{
         echo "Соединение не удалось, ошибка:";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }


    function get_cat() {
        global $conn;
        //запрос к базе данных
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.menu_user";
        $result = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
            if(!$result) {
            return NULL;
             sqlsrv_errors();   
        }
        $arr_cat = array();
        if(sqlsrv_num_rows($result) != 0) {

            //В цикле формируем массив
            for($i = 0; $i < sqlsrv_num_rows($result);$i++) {
                $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,sqlsrv_ASSOC);
                 print_r($row);
                //Формируем массив, где ключами являются адишники на родительские категории
                if(empty($arr_cat[$row['parent_id']])) {
                    $arr_cat[$row['parent_id']] = array();
                }
                $arr_cat[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
            }
            //возвращаем массив
            print_r($row);
            return $arr_cat;
        }
    }



//////// ФОРМИРОВАНИЕ БЛОКА МЕНЮ ДЛЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ///////////////////////////




//вывод каталога с помощью рекурсии
function view_cat($arr,$parent_id = 0) {



    //Условия выхода из рекурсии
    if(empty($arr[$parent_id])) {
        return;
    }
    echo '<ul>';
    //перебираем в цикле массив и выводим на экран
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr[$parent_id]);$i++) {
        echo '<li><a href="?category_id='.$arr[$parent_id][$i]['id'].
                    '&parent_id='.$parent_id.'">'
                    .$arr[$parent_id][$i]['title'].'</a>';
        //рекурсия - проверяем нет ли дочерних категорий
        view_cat($arr,$arr[$parent_id][$i]['id']);
        echo '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

}?>
```

вызываю функцию c **index.php**:

```
view_cat($result);
```

но почему-то не видит переменную:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: result in **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\stackoverflow\nw\modules\menu.php on line 32**
```

если просто вызваю функцию **get_cat()**
 то ничего не выдает, хотя по идее должен сформировать массив

при распечатке массива

**$result = get_cat();
print_r($result);**

тоже ничего не выдает

вчера целый вечер потратил, решения не нашел. буду признателен, если подскажите что с этим делать)

В целом структура такая:
**index.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf8");
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/media.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>




    </head>

    <body>
    <header>

    <img src="img/logo.jpg" class="logo_img">

    </header>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 no-float">


            <nav>
     <?php


    include_once 'modules\menu.php';

    get_cat();




     ?>
     </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 no-float">



    <h1>Заголовок</h1>

TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
    TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
    TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
    TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
    TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    </body>





    </html>
```

**menu.php**

```
<?php




 session_start();


 if ( isset( $_GET['l']) )
 {

     $_SESSION['levelacc'] = $_GET['l'];;

 }


 else {

     echo "Error enter";
 }


 $dostup=$_SESSION['levelacc'];

 switch ($dostup) {
case "user":


//вывод меню 
include 'core\config.php';
get_cat();
echo '<div style="width:300px;float:left; padding:10px; border:1px solid #074776">';




echo '</div>';




    break;





case "spec":
echo "MENU FOR SPEC";
    break;




case "oper":
  include 'modules\modlvl\l3.php';
    break;
}








?>
```

Comment: тоже пусто ничего

Comment: добавил, и дополнил топик выше, что-бы была виждна полная картина,я просто 2 жень с этим сижу, уже голова не работет) только не ругайтесь, я только учусь)

Comment: хммм ничего не выдает(

Comment: в самой базе все норм) выдал всю таблицу как и должно  быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте такую функцию:

```
function get_cat() {
    global $conn;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM dbo.menu_user";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    if (false === $result) {
        die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    //var_dump(sqlsrv_num_rows($result));

    $arr_cat = array();
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $arr_cat[(int) $row['parent_id']][] = $row; 
    }
    return $arr_cat;
}
```

Comment: спасибо  вышел массив, а объясните тупому, чтоя я делал не так

Comment: @b.tard2016, не знаю :) Вероятно дело в константе `sqlsrv_ASSOC`, а надо было `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC`. А может в чем другом. Когда пишете код, смотрите в руководство. Там к каждой функции куча (обычно) примеров использования. Вот http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Comment: не подскажешь еще ?) в config.php есть функция  function view_cat (это все я выложил в листинг вверху)
при вызове ее из файла menu.php (view_cat($result);)  сыпется ошибка, что не не видит переменную, хотя функция get_menu лежит в том-же файле (conf.php) и он подключен инклудом